# Need help implementing an algorithm to solve roots of a transcendental equation

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, fourier-transform

I'm trying to implement [this algorithm](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijem/2015/523043/) but I'm having problems reproducing the exemple that it gives a solution to.

The general method that I tried is:

1. Make a grid $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, with say N=256 points in it
2. Create a complex vector $G(\theta) = \frac{1}{F(e^{i\theta})}$, where $F(z) = z\tan(z) - 1$ is the complex extension of the transcendental equation in question.
3. Solve $G_{k} = \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} G(\theta)e^{ik\theta}d\theta$ for as many $k$ as I need.

> If I understood correctly, there'll be a $nroot\times nroot$ symmetric matrix with $2\times nroot$ independent elements. E.g for $nroot = 3$ I will have to solve for $G_{1},G_{2},G_{3},G_{4},G_{5},G_{6}$. Eventually $G_{6}$ will go to the right side of the equation as when we fix the value of $c_{3}$.

4. Solve the system $A\cdot X = -B$

The problem that I'm getting is the following:

The eventual values of $c_{k}$ are *complex*, and in the system that the author gets to in (18) there are just real numbers. The author mentions the use of the routine *cfft* which I'm unaware of, I solved the integral explicitly and with ordinary FFT and in neither I get real numbers. Even the real part of the $c_{k}$'s I'm getting, even though are of the same order of the solution it is far from it.

My solution is just wrong, I get the wrong system therefore the wrong $c_{k}$'s and I'm unable to get to the solution.

Comment: Your title doesn't reflects the topic rather than your actual question.

Comment: I'll change to a more appropriate one .